# Unable to retrieve user information in SharePoint endpoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapps-forms, service-endpoint

I am trying to validate if a user exists in a user group created in SharePoint.

I am trying to get this information in Power Apps, through the trigger "Send HTTP"

I pass the following in the Uri:

```
_api/web/sitegroups/getByName('user group')/users?$filter=Email eq 'trigger body'
```

When i test run with an email address, it does not return the full user properties.

Can you please advise where am i going wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

The above endpoint is for checking if the user is present in the specified Group. 
[image]
if you want to get detailed user properties, you may consider using below API:

- [GetPropertiesFor method](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-rest-reference/dn790354%28v%3Doffice.15%29#getpropertiesfor-method)